# FileHelper MasterDetail

Tags: c#, filehelpers

Can anyone point me on how to use the MasterDetailEngine for FileHelper?

I have:

```
 var engine = new MasterDetailEngine<MyHeader, MyDetail>(new MasterDetailSelector(ExampleSelector));
 var result = engine.ReadFile(filePath);
```

Now my question in particular is with the MasterDetailSelector.
I have a MyHeader and MyDetail classes, both have a FIXED length and both have the same length.

So how can I write my selector? (See below what I'm trying to do)

```
private RecordAction ExampleSelector(string record)
{
    // If the first record occurrence
        return RecordAction.Master;
    // else
        return RecordAction.Detail;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use HeaderText property instead MasterDetail engine only to read the head line.

Comment: I want to read all the lines in and set it as a header/detail object.